# How to get OpenX ad server work with iOS framework?

Tags: ios, mobile, ads, openx

I have installed OpenX ad server to my domain www.mydomain.com/openx. It works great, but now I want to use these ads in my iOS app. I use OpenX iOS SDK (http://www.openx.com/mobile/sdk-downloads).

My main problem is that I don't know sure what to put in these parameters:

```
[self.adBanner setDomain:@"www.mydomain.com/openx" portraitAdUID:@"" landscapeAdUID:@""];
```

What means ADUID?

Answer (score 0):

It is an "Ad Unit ID". From the OpenX documentation:

> Ad units are virtual representations of the specific areas in your
>   site where you want to display ads. You can set up ad units for ads.
>   When you create an ad unit, you specify attributes for it that will
>   determine the kinds of ads that will display there. OpenX uses these
>   ad unit attributes to generate the ad code that will make real-time
>   requests to the ad server.

You need to set up the ad unit in your admin view of your ad server installation, then copy the assigned ad unit ID to your code in the `portraitAdUID` and `landscapeAdUID` arguments.

Comment: For some reason I can't find the Ad units from the openX server. There are only zones. Where can I manage ad units?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.openx.com/sdk/  for OpenX Enterprise Ad Server .

OpenX Sales their Openx  Source PHP Code to Revive Ad Server Team .

To Delivery Ads on Mobile App using openx-2.8.11 or Revive-Adserver(http://www.revive-adserver.com/releases/revive-adserver-3.0.0.zip) you need to write Mobile SDKs.

Ad Units in OpenX Enterprise  - Ad Unit ID

Zones in Revive Ad Server (OpenX Source) - Zone ID

You can write the Objective-C code to Send Ad Request & Receive Ad Response(Banner,Rich Media,Video)

mAdserv -Open Source Mobile Ad Server

Download the mAdserv , you can have SDK for Android and iOS.

Their SDK also Open Source .

You use or customize  the codes of sdk

Regards,

Chinnu.G